# How to get the extends of single area-type geojson file?

Tags: google-maps, geojson

I need the google map to zoom into the extends of single area-type geojson-file.

I can load the geojson file to google maps and make it a data layer:

```
var myArea = new google.maps.Data();
myArea.loadGeoJson('myArea.geojson');
```

I can set its settings:

```
myArea.setStyle({
strokeColor:"#F00",
fillColor:"#00F"
};
```

But I cannot zoom the view according to its borders.

For "map.fitBounds()" to work, I would need to get the LatLngBounds of myArea.

**How to get LatLngBounds from the geoJson-google map data layer?**
I have found a lot of information for many other types of data (sheets, polygons, several layers, points, lines) but not one for single geojson-data layer.

I have tried for example:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 
map.data.forEach(function(myArea){
   myArea.getGeometry().forEachLatLng(function(latlng){
   bounds.extend(latlng);
   });
});
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

I have also tried to find the extends manually:

```
var SW = myArea.getSouthWest();
var NW = myArea.getNorthEast();
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(SW,NE);
```

With no success. I think the problem is in the concept of google data layer, but I haven't found anything to go around this problem. Any ideas how to get the bounds of single geojson google map data layer?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  The first example _should_ work (except that `forEach` is probably asynchronous, so you would need to account for that)

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` is asynchronous.  You need to set the map bounds either in each function call or when all are complete. This works for me:

```
map.data.forEach(function(myArea) {
  myArea.getGeometry().forEachLatLng(function(latlng) {
    bounds.extend(latlng);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2ks04z3k/6/)

[image]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  // Create a simple map.
  features = [];
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: -28,
      lng: 137.883
    }
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
  });
  // process the loaded GeoJSON data.
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  map.data.addGeoJson(data);
  map.data.forEach(function(myArea) {
    myArea.getGeometry().forEachLatLng(function(latlng) {
      bounds.extend(latlng);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
var data = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "test",
      "desc": "test desc",
      "inDailyProgram": true,
      "color": "red"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [
            35.188327,
            31.699929,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.187895,
            31.699669,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.187014,
            31.699729,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.186867,
            31.700016,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.186783,
            31.700395,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.186921,
            31.700787,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.187232,
            31.701291,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.18763,
            31.701844,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.187442,
            31.702328,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.18692,
            31.702779,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.187064,
            31.703654,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.187433,
            31.703794,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.188155,
            31.70344,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.188921,
            31.702917,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.189348,
            31.702887,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.189828,
            31.70302,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.190313,
            31.703443,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.190359,
            31.704104,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.190224,
            31.704348,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.189797,
            31.704585,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.189753,
            31.704948,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.189847,
            31.705107,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.190187,
            31.705015,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.190604,
            31.705041,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.190931,
            31.705171,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.191435,
            31.70526,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.191861,
            31.705231,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.192482,
            31.705008,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.192945,
            31.704893,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.193564,
            31.704449,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.192869,
            31.704004,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.192256,
            31.703737,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.191754,
            31.703371,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.191306,
            31.703001,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.190838,
            31.702632,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.190546,
            31.70221,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.190348,
            31.701739,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.190323,
            31.701589,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.189814,
            31.701624,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.189443,
            31.701456,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.189108,
            31.701217,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.188509,
            31.700359,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.188327,
            31.699929,
            0
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "test",
      "desc": "test desc",
      "inDailyProgram": true,
      "color": "red"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [
            35.209224,
            31.718497,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.209775,
            31.718459,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.210282,
            31.717788,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.210741,
            31.71723,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.21132,
            31.716803,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.211748,
            31.716193,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.212124,
            31.715632,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.212315,
            31.714798,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.21227,
            31.714137,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.212647,
            31.713599,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.21316,
            31.713412,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.214134,
            31.713095,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.215018,
            31.712675,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.215822,
            31.7119,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.21577,
            31.711156,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.215564,
            31.710175,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.215104,
            31.709128,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.21473,
            31.708518,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.214301,
            31.707911,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.214086,
            31.707207,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.213709,
            31.706154,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.213519,
            31.705807,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.212415,
            31.705441,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.211313,
            31.705103,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.210114,
            31.704964,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.20915,
            31.705031,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.208402,
            31.704612,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.207939,
            31.704119,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.207657,
            31.704636,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.207123,
            31.704922,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.206421,
            31.705164,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.205969,
            31.70529,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.205926,
            31.705613,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.205553,
            31.705808,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.205577,
            31.706157,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.205694,
            31.706459,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.205902,
            31.70686,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.206285,
            31.707193,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.206113,
            31.707375,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.206005,
            31.707544,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.206139,
            31.707746,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.206713,
            31.708194,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.207228,
            31.708428,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.207474,
            31.708798,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.207463,
            31.709435,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.207359,
            31.709878,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.207255,
            31.710418,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.207232,
            31.71089,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.20712,
            31.711257,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.206802,
            31.711473,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.206408,
            31.711645,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.206061,
            31.711753,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.205639,
            31.711857,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.205398,
            31.711766,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.205213,
            31.711698,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.205289,
            31.711992,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.205266,
            31.712464,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.205096,
            31.712808,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.204885,
            31.713348,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.204829,
            31.71414,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.204947,
            31.714644,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.205089,
            31.715104,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.205489,
            31.715687,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.205906,
            31.716113,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.206464,
            31.716586,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.20684,
            31.716421,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.207254,
            31.716005,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.207524,
            31.715517,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.207901,
            31.714965,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.207949,
            31.714464,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.208022,
            31.713919,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.20835,
            31.713855,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.208542,
            31.714229,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.208847,
            31.71465,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.209151,
            31.715044,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.20929,
            31.71545,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.209362,
            31.715694,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.209315,
            31.716214,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.209177,
            31.716619,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.209031,
            31.716906,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.208958,
            31.717132,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.208853,
            31.717333,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.208878,
            31.717691,
            0
          ],
          [
            35.209224,
            31.718497,
            0
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }]
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: The problem seems to be the "data" which you are giving as an argument in "map.data.addGeoJson(data)". I don't know what to put as "data". I have loaded the geojson data with myArea.loadGeoJson('myArea.geojson') but it doesn't work if I give that as an argument like: "map.data.addGeoJson(myArea)".

Comment: If you had provided a [mcve] that demonstrates the isssue, I could make my example with your data.  `.addGeoJson(data)` takes valid GeoJSON as a string, `loadGeoJson(URL)` loads valid GeoJSON from an external URL.

Comment: In your code the geoJson is apparently parsed to the bottom of the code and saved as "data" variable. In your code I don't see reference to geoJson file. I'm having a geoJson file but I cannot refer to it. If I use the code you provided I get the "data is not defined at initialize" -error.

Comment: You can load the geoJson with either function, just depends on where it is.

Comment: I have loaded it already with myArea.loadGeoJson('myArea.geoJson'). After that I have changed its styling and put it on the map without problems so it should be valid. I also tested my geoJson-file with "Google Map's Data layer: Drag and Drop" and it worked. But if I put it to your code it doesn't work and I get the error "data is not defined". Do you make manually that "data" variable at the end of your code? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: As an answer for your note of providing example, it is difficult due to code being in php. The problem is that my geoJson is dynamic so I cannot make data-variable manually as you have. Is it really so that I cannot just use external geoJson and get the zoom according its extend? I saw you had commented similar problem earlier where the guy didn't found solution either in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334931/loading-a-local-geojson-file-and-using-it-with-the-google-maps-javascript-api-v3

Comment: PHP runs on the server.  The  Google Maps Javascript API v3 is in the client.  You can provide a HTML/Javascript example that reproduces your problem.  However, to do that, you need to understand the restrictions on `loadGeoJson` and why I created my example with `addGeoJson` and a GeoJSON string.

Comment: I didn't ask an example of addGeoJson and added GeoJSON string. I asked google map to zoom into the extends of single area-type geojson-file. Now I know how to do it and I will post the answer soon since there are many people asking the same thing with no proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set your map according to extend of one area-type (not point or line) GeoJson-file ("yourgeojsonfile")

```
function initialize() {
// Create new base map to your div called "map".
// Map options removed since map zoomed according to your geojson file
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"))  
// Load yourgeojsonfile and zoom the map to its extends
        map.data.loadGeoJson('yourgeojsonfile',null,function(){
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                map.data.forEach(function(feature){
                    processPoints(feature.getGeometry(),bounds.extend,bounds);
                });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
}

// Function for getting the boundaries of geojson (one point area possibility removed)
function processPoints(geometry,callback,thisArg){
    if(geometry instanceof google.maps.LatLng){
                callback.call(thisArg,geometry);
        }
        else{
                geometry.getArray().forEach(function(x){
                    processPoints(x,callback,thisArg);
                });
        }
}
```